# StackOverflow when dynamically adding child elements to Path

Tags: c#, wpf, stack-overflow

I'm trying to dynamically add some paths to a Grid, but this generates an infinite loop that results in a SO.

```
    private void SubLayout_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeometryGroup myGeometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();
        EllipseGeometry myEllipseGeometry = new EllipseGeometry();
        myEllipseGeometry.Center = new Point(100, 41.5);
        myEllipseGeometry.RadiusX = 5;
        myEllipseGeometry.RadiusY = 5;
        myGeometryGroup.Children.Add(myGeometryGroup);
        points.Data = myGeometryGroup;
    }
```

XAML:

```
   <Path x:Name="points" Fill="Gold" Stroke="Black" 
StrokeThickness="1"> </Path>
```

Error:

System.StackOverflowException was unhandled

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you're not doing anything with your ellipse there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see  `myGeometryGroup.Children.Add(myGeometryGroup);`, you *probabbly*
would do

```
myGeometryGroup.Children.Add(myEllipseGeometry);
```